# Android usecase with single source of truth

Tags: android, android-room, android-architecture-components, kotlin-coroutines, use-case

After reading [this article](https://www.techyourchance.com/repository-android-anti-pattern/)(Repository Anti-Pattern in Android), I'm not gonna use repository pattern but usecases in my project. I'd like to use room database as the single source of truth. The article says "If a flow happens to depend on both networking and persistence, you can pass the respective abstractions into use case class and it’ll “arbitrate” between these sources". But I didn't find a way to achieve this.

```
class GetFeedsUseCase @Inject constructor(
    private val appDatabase: AppDatabase,
    private val service: RemoteApiService,
    @IoDispatcher dispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher
): UseCase<Int, Timeline>(dispatcher) {

    override suspend fun execute(parameters: Int): List<Feed> {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }
}
```

Is there a practical way to implement this?

Comment: architectures are logical groupings and classifications of code, while they provide guidelines, implementation still changes per team/person. failing to find a way to implement something in an architecture therefore means it's (likely) a failure with understanding, not really with code. you might find better answers on software engineer or somewhere else where people could explain the concept or implementation, as this question doesn't have one specific coding answer. only my suggestion

Comment: First thing first, you've shared a link stating Repositories being anti-pattern. I can suggest that don't see only one side of coin, always flip it first and check another side as well. Now back to the point, the project I'm working in right now consist both of them (Use cases as well as Repositories). So, it's all about denying to accept about some concept because, if any perfect architecture exists, wouldn't we all agreed to use that one only?